# If I am referencing the same primary source but in another book, can I write "english translation" (Turabian)

Tags: chicago-manual-of-style

I wrote:

“Statuette Naophore du Vatican Nº 158 [113],” ca. 518 ʙ.c, in *La première domination Perse en Égypte*, trans. ed. Georges H. Posener (Cairo: Institut Français d’Archéologie Orientale, 1936), p.6, ark:/13960/t70w3qp5w; english translation in *The Persian Empire: A Corpus of Sources of the Achaemenid Period*, trans. ed. Amélie Kuhrt (Abingdon: Routledge, 2007), p.117, ark:/13960/t92892p39.

I am using Posener for the hieroglyphs and Kuhrt for the English translation, but its the text in both books, it seems redundent to do it otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you cite the same work in two languages?

Comment: And is that example part of your body text or a footnote or an entry in your bibliography?

Comment: @Ben I am citing it in two languages because I include the hieroglyph in my text. Its the footnote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your body text includes quotes in both hieroglyphs and English, like this:

> ... bla bla bla. The prophecies of Neferti say:
>
> > [image]
> > <sup>1</sup>
> >
> > *The sun will separate from the people. Although it will rise at its time, no one will know that the day has arrived.*<sup>2</sup>
>
> Bla bla bla ...

You could then easily give the sources separately, like this:

> ---
>
> 1 “Statuette Naophore du Vatican Nº 158 [113],” ca. 518 ʙ.c, in La première domination Perse en Égypte, trans. ed. Georges H. Posener (Cairo: Institut Français d’Archéologie Orientale, 1936), p.6, ark:/13960/t70w3qp5w
>
> 2 The Persian Empire: A Corpus of Sources of the Achaemenid Period, trans. ed. Amélie Kuhrt (Abingdon: Routledge, 2007), p.117, ark:/13960/t92892p39.

But if you want to cite both sources in the same footnote, your example is fine, too.